# Workflow and Hierarchical Custom Setting

Tags: workflow, customsetting

If a Hierarchical Custom Setting is used as part of a Workflow Rule, does the workflow access the User version (assuming the user had a custom setting) or the System/Organizational version?

Answer (score 1):

It works according to the documentation:

> The hierarchy logic checks the organization, profile, and user
>   settings for the current user and returns the most specific, or
>   “lowest,” value. In the hierarchy, settings for an organization are
>   overridden by profile settings, which, in turn, are overridden by user
>   settings.

Comment: I understand that is the way hierarchical custom settings should work.  If I have a workflow on the User object, though, would it still access the user version or the system context?  I'm a little fuzzy on that part.

Comment: User who caused the workflow to occur